# classify the set of polygons from side lengths in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a file containing comma-separated list of side lengths (for example “3,4,8,5,7” represents one polygon per line).

In JavaScript how do I classify the set of polygons into four mutually exclusive subsets: triangles, rectangles, squares, and everything else. The union of all four subsets should be the original set of polygons. All the sides of the polygons are connected and the angles between them are irrelevant, only consider the lengths.

Comment: I was able to parse input from file, stored it in an array of arrays kind of a structure ex.: [[1,2,3],[1,2,1,2],[2,2,2,2]] where each index of array represents the polygon lengths(subarray) and printing the type of polygon.

Comment: Please tell me if this is the right approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the solution for your whole problem [here at my Github repo](https://github.com/dhirajpatra/polygons_to_triangles_squares_triangle_others)

Though I am providing the solutions here bellow:

```
/**
 * count a value how many times in an array
 */
function countValueInArray(array, niddle) {
    return array.filter(item => item == niddle).length;
}

/**
 * read file 
 */
var fileText = [];

function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                // when text file content json : [["1,3,1"], ["2,2,2,2"], ["2,4,2,4"], ["4,2,3"], ["3,4,2,6"]]
                //fileText = JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);

                // for line separated file
                fileText = rawFile.responseText.split('\n');
                //alert(fileText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

/**
 * this will check whether it can make a triangle
 */
function checkTriangle(set) {
    if (set.length != 3) {
        return false;
    }
    var a = parseInt(set[0]);
    var b = parseInt(set[1]);
    var c = parseInt(set[2]);

    if (((a + b) > c) && ((a + c) > b) && ((b + c) > a)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * this will check whether it can make a square
 */
function checkSquare(set) {
    if (set.length != 4) {
        return false;
    }

    var a = parseInt(set[0]);
    var b = parseInt(set[1]);
    var c = parseInt(set[2]);
    var d = parseInt(set[3]);

    var equal = set.reduce(function(sum, val) {
        return val === set[0];
    });

    return equal;
}

/**
 * this will check whether it can make rectangle or not
 */
function checkRectangle(set) {
    if (set.length != 4) {
        return false;
    }

    var a = parseInt(set[0]);
    var b = parseInt(set[1]);
    var c = parseInt(set[2]);
    var d = parseInt(set[3]);

    if (((countValueInArray(set, a) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, b) == 2)) || ((countValueInArray(set, c) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, d) == 2)) || ((countValueInArray(set, a) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, c) == 2)) || ((countValueInArray(set, a) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, d) == 2)) || ((countValueInArray(set, b) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, d) == 2)) || ((countValueInArray(set, b) == 2) && (countValueInArray(set, c) == 2))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

// create polygons array
var polygons = [];
readTextFile('./polygons.txt');
//document.write(fileText.length);
fileText.forEach(function(p) {
    polygons.push(p);
});
//document.write(polygons[0]);
var triangles = [];
var squares = [];
var rectangles = [];
var others = [];
var result;
// polygons loop of all sets
for (let i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    var set;
    set = polygons[i].split(',');
    //document.writeln(set.length);

    if (set.length == 3) {
        result = checkTriangle(set);
        if (result == true) {
            triangles.push(set);
        } else {
            others.push(set);
        }

    } else if (set.length == 4) {
        result = checkSquare(set);
        if (result == true) {
            squares.push(set);
            //rectangles.push(set);
        } else if (checkRectangle(set) == true) {
            rectangles.push(set);
        } else {
            others.push(set);
        }

    } else {
        others.push(set);
    }
}

/*let unionOfAll = new Set(triangles, squares, rectangles, others);
unionOfAll.forEach(function(set){
    document.writeln(set);
});*/
// as they are already mutually exclusive set/array
let unionOfAll = triangles.concat(squares.concat(triangles.concat(others)));

document.write("Original polygons txt file contents: <br>" + fileText.join("<br>") + "<br><hr><br>");

document.write("Mutually exclusive sets:-<br>");
document.write("Triangles: " + JSON.stringify(triangles) + "<br>");
document.write("Squares: " + JSON.stringify(squares) + "<br>");
document.write("Rectangles: " + JSON.stringify(rectangles) + "<br>");
document.write("Others: " + JSON.stringify(others) + "<br><hr><br>");

document.write("Union of all: " + JSON.stringify(unionOfAll) + "<br>");
```

And you have to create a polygons text file with contents like bellow:

> 1,3,1
>   2,2,2,2
>   4,5,6
>   2,4,2,4
>   4,2,3
>   3,4,2,6
>   8,8,8,8
>   5,5,6,6
>   2,4,3,5,4

Answer (score 0):

Simply split by , and get the length:

```
var polygons={};
["1,3,1", "2,2,2,2"]. forEach(function(p){
  p=p.split(",");
 (polygons[p.length]=polygons[p.length]||[]).push(p);
});
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
polygons[3]//all triangles: [[1,3,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code jonas, Is there a general method which takes the lengths as input, does some computation and tell what type of a polygon is it.

Comment: @bluestacksadmin i dont get your question. Simply use an array with names, e.g [undefined,"line","triangle","rectangle","pentagon"]